# c# '' is a variable but is used as a type. How can i solve this issue?

Tags: c#

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    var CheckingAccount = new CheckingAccount {AccountNumber = "0000123456", FirstName = "Michael", LastName = "Sullivan", Balance = 500 };
    return View(CheckingAccount);
}
```

Comment: You have named the variable the same as the type, so it will shadow the type.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast answer. I wanted to use a variable there, not a type. What should i change the syntax to?

Comment: `var checkingAccount = new CheckingAccount {...}; return View(checkingAccount);`

Comment: Thanks, haha i knew i was definitely not ok today...

Comment: @fatihyener in the future when using the key word `var` that's the same as doing the following `CheckingAccount checkingAccount = new CheckingAccount()` when hovering over the var key word when you step through the code  past the `var` decloration, it will tell you what the datatype of the variable is ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    var checkingAccount = new CheckingAccount {AccountNumber = "0000123456", FirstName = "Michael", LastName = "Sullivan", Balance = 500 };
    return View(checkingAccount);
}
```